# Unable to run test from Jenkins - cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

My goal is to run my first time Selenium tests with Jenkins (not local).

**So what I did**:

1. I created google cloud server
2. I installed Jenkins on my server thanks to this guide: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine
3. Created job with "plugin maven project",
   connect my bitbucket project to the "Source Code Management"
   screenshot [job maven project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZHdT.png)
4. Jenkins Configuration I installed JDK and Maven

Now the problem is when I try to run the job, my test doesn't work because Jenkins can't find web driver:

```
INFO: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create new webdriver
/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/2.35/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4K9O.png)

What should i do ?

1. I know that I don't have that path `/home/tomcat/.m2/..` on my server 
   and I don't know how to create it
2. I installed `libnss3` libraries

Please help

Comment: Are you using Selenide by any chance?

Comment: give your java code

Comment: yes i use Selenide !! sorry forget to write it